# Compare String with list of strings in bash

Tags: linux, bash, azure-devops, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to compare the service with a list of available service names, if service is found in the list then do update the service otherwise deploy the service.
But below condition only deploying new service even when service available in list variable?

```
SERVNAME=ner
SERVICE=$(az ml service list -g $(ml_rg) --workspace-name $(ml_ws) --model-name $(model_name) --query "[].name")

if [[ "$SERVNAME" == "$SERVICE" ]];
then
   echo "Service Found: $(SERVNAME) and updating the service"
   az ml service update --name $(AKS_DEPLOYMENT_NAME) \
          --model '$(MODEL_NAME):$(MODEL_VERSION)' \
          --dc aksDeploymentConfig.json \
          --ic inferenceConfig.json \
          -e $(ml_env_name) --ev $(ml_env_version) \
          -g $(ml_rg) --workspace-name $(ml_ws) -v ;
else
   echo "Service Not found and starting deploying new service"
   az ml model deploy --name $(AKS_DEPLOYMENT_NAME) --model \
   '$(MODEL_NAME):$(MODEL_VERSION)' \
          --compute-target $(ml_aks_name) \
          --ic inferenceConfig.json \
          -e $(ml_env_name) --ev $(ml_env_version) \
          --dc aksDeploymentConfig.json \
          -g $(ml_rg) --workspace-name $(ml_ws) \
          --overwrite -v ;
fi
```

Example list

```
SERVNAME="ner"
SERVICE=[ "ner", "aks-gpu-ner-0306210907", "aks-gpu-ner-30012231", "aks-gpu-ner-1305211336"]
```

Comment: There are a bunch of things here that aren't correct bash syntax. It looks like you're using `$( )` to get variables' values, but that's the syntax for running a command and getting its output; I think you want `${ }` instead. Speaking of which, variable references like that should almost always be in double-quotes (and especially not single-quotes, since they prevent variable expansion). [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) will point out many of the problems. Also, the example value for `SERVICE` at the end is not valid syntax; does the value actually contain brackets and quotes?

Comment: @GordonDavisson Yes service variable with bracket & quote is result of running "az ml service list " command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the `az ml` command returns a json array string and you want to
check if the array includes the value of variable `SERVNAME`, would you
please try:

```
SERVNAME="ner"
SERVICE='[ "ner", "aks-gpu-ner-0306210907", "aks-gpu-ner-30012231", "aks-gpu-ner-1305211336"]'

if [[ $SERVICE =~ "\"$SERVNAME\"" ]]; then
    echo "Service Found"
    # put your command here to update the service
else
    echo "Service Not Found"
    # put your command here to deploy new service
fi
```

The regex operator `$SERVICE =~ "\"$SERVNAME\""` matches if the string `$SERVICE`
contains the substring `$SERVNAME` enclosed with double quotes.

If `jq` is available, you could also say:

```
result=$(echo "$SERVICE" | jq --arg var "$SERVNAME" '. | index($var)')
if [[ $result != "null" ]]; then
    echo "Service Found"
else
    echo "Service Not Found"
fi
```

Comment: Does the method will check  for an exact match with SERVNAME in SERVICE list

Comment: Absolutely. As for the 1st solution, please note the rhs `"$SERVNAME"` is surrounded by double quotes. The double quotes are *not* the variable wrapper often used in bash scripting *but* the part of the regex. Then the partial match is *not* allowed such as
`"ner"` with `"aks-gpu-ner-0306210907"`. The 2nd `jq` solution also finds the exact match.

Comment: @tshiono That's incorrect, in the regex version the double-quotes are not matched as part of the pattern, but treated as meaning that the double-quoted section should be matched literally rather than as regex syntax. That is, `.*` will match any sequence of characters, but `".*"` will only match a literal period followed by an asterisk. You can test this by removing `"ner"` from the `SERVICE` list, or by setting `SERVNAME="gpu-ner"` -- both will still match. You need `if [[ $SERVICE =~ "\"$SERVNAME\"" ]]` (which has both literal *and* syntactic double-quotes).

Comment: @GordonDavisson thank you for pointing me out. Year, you're right. I've corrected my answer accordingly . sree, would you please take a look my update? Thanks.

Comment: @tshiono Looks good, I updated the explanatory text to match.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I do appreciate your help and kindness.

Answer (score 3):

Bash doesn't have lists it has arrays.

To check if array contains a value use the following:

```sh
SERVNAME="ner"
SERVICE=("ner" "aks-gpu-ner-0306210907" "aks-gpu-ner-30012231" "aks-gpu-ner-1305211336")

if [[ " ${SERVICE[*]} " =~ " ${SERVNAME} " ]]; then
    echo "Match Found For Service: $SERVNAME"
else
    echo "Match Not Found For Service: $SERVNAME"
fi
```

Comment: variables are referenced from Azure devops variables setion and service variable is a result of running "az ml service list" command so that's why variable is enclosed with brackets & quotes.